# Positioning text next to other text on D3.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I'm working with a design that has a legend and that legend has two bits of text next to each other. Due to their styling, I believe I have to append two different `g` to make it work.

[image]

I was sort of success with it and with some online resources but what I'm seeing is that with a *small primary text* my second text is not being placed correctly.

Here's a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-matsumoto-y3opmh?file=/src/App.tsx) with the running example (notice how the object with the **Previous versions** label shows the percentage with some distance but the one with **0.0.1** doesn't.

Here's my code with the relevant bits

```js
import { FC, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'

interface Props {
  data: Array<any>
}

/**
 * Taken from
 * https://bl.ocks.org/eesur/287b5700b5881e8899cc7301a5fefb94
 */
const dataConstructor = (data: any[], total: number) => {
  // use scale to get percent values
  const percent = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, total]).range([0, 100])
  // filter out data that has zero values
  // also get mapping for next placement
  // (save having to format data for d3 stack)
  let cumulative = 0
  const _data = data
    .map((d) => {
      cumulative += d.value!
      return {
        value: d.value,
        // want the cumulative to prior value (start of rect)
        cumulative: cumulative - d.value!,
        label: d.label,
        percent: percent(d.value!),
        color: d.color,
      }
    })
    .filter((d) => d.value! > 0)
  return _data
}

/**
 * Taken from
 * https://gist.github.com/huytd/327e453c95ca3edadb32d0c867e2561b
 */
function textSize(text: any) {
  let container = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  container
    .append('text')
    .style('transform', 'translate(-99999, y: -99999')
    .text(text)

  const size = container.node()!.getBBox()

  container.remove()

  return { width: size.width, height: size.height }
}

const drawChart = (element: any, data: any) => {
  const f = d3.format('.1f')

  const totalValueFromData = data.reduce(
    (prev: number, curr: any) => prev + curr.value!,
    0
  )

  const height = 36
  const width = 472
  const halfBarHeight = height / 2

  const _data = dataConstructor(data, totalValueFromData)

  const xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, totalValueFromData])
    .range([0, width])

  const svg = d3
    .select(element)
    .append('svg')
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 472 102')

  [... boring graph stuff]

  const legend = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(0, 24)')

  /**
   * Legend Squares
   */
  legend
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('legendSquares')
    .data(_data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', 2)
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
      return 30 + i * 20
    })
    .attr('width', 10)
    .attr('height', 10)
    .attr('rx', '1.2')
    .style('fill', (d: any) => d.color)

  /**
   * Legend Strings
   */
  legend
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('legendStrings')
    .data(_data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
    .attr('x', 20)
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
      return 30 + i * 20 + 9
    })
    .text(function (d: any) {
      return d.label
    })
    .style('fill', '#4D5056')
    .style('font-size', '11px')
    .style('line-height', '14px')

  /**
   * Legend Percentages
   */
  legend
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('legendPercentages')
    .data(_data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
    .attr('x', function (d: any) {
      // here's where I'm trying to place the percentage close to my other text in the legend
      return textSize(d.label).width
    })
    .attr('y', function (d, i) {
      return 30 + i * 20 + 9
    })
    .text((d) => f(d.percent) + '%')
    .style('fill', '#868C97')
    .style('font-size', '11px')
    .style('line-height', '14px')
}

const HorizontalStackedLineChart: FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  const horizontalStackedLineChartRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (horizontalStackedLineChartRef.current && data) {
      d3.select(horizontalStackedLineChartRef.current).selectAll('svg').remove()

      drawChart(horizontalStackedLineChartRef.current, data)
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [horizontalStackedLineChartRef, data])

  return (
    <div
      ref={horizontalStackedLineChartRef}
      data-testid="horizontalStackedLineChar"
    />
  )
}

export default HorizontalStackedLineChart
```

```js
  const data = [
    {
      label: "0.0.1",
      value: 100,
      color: "#ff0000"
    },
    {
      label: "Previous versions",
      value: 200,
      color: "#00ff00"
    }
  ];
```

What am I doing wrong? And if there's a better option to make this work? From what I could see, this seemed to be the only actual way of doing it but I can't figure out why the positioning of the text is inconsistent

Comment: You can use a <tspan> inside the text like so `<text text-anchor="start" x="20" y="59" style="fill: rgb(77, 80, 86); font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px;">Previous versions <tspan style="fill: whatever" >67.7%</tspan></text>`

Comment: @enxaneta, that works  I was able to position the `tspan` as I wanted by appending it after my `text` and giving it a `.attr('dx', 6)` to place it where I want it!